# Getting duplicate SQL values in MySQL in unioned table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a database query in MySQL :

```
SELECT id, number_id, number, year
    FROM
        tb_figures WHERE (id = 7 AND year = 45 AND number IS NULL) 
    AND  
        (id = 7 AND year = 47 AND number IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY
        number_id;
```

but it returns an empty table although there are cases where it should match.

I want to check if **number** IS NOT NULL when **year = 47** and if number IS NULL when **year = 45** and only then display both results in a table.

EDIT : As stated in the comments I got the logic wrong, and the above query can not work.

I managed to get closer with this query :

```
SELECT
    id, number_id, number, year
FROM 
    tb_figures
WHERE
    id = 7 AND  (year = 45 AND number IS NOT NULL)

UNION

SELECT
    id, number_id, number, year
FROM 
    tb_figures
WHERE
    id = 7 AND (year = 47 AND kennzahl IS NULL)
ORDER BY
     number_id;
```

But now I need to display only the rows which have the same **number_id**.

Is there anything I can add to the query to display only the rows with duplicate **number_id**´s?

Comment: I think the `WHERE` part is wrong. You search one line with `id = 7` with different values on same column (`year` and `number`)? The `id` is unique?

Comment: *"it returns an empty table although there are cases where it should match"* - Not really. A record where `number IS NULL` and `number IS NOT NULL` at the same time cannot exist. You want `OR`, not `AND`

Comment: that AND split - what does using an OR give back?

Comment: well someone popped an answer using what I asked but got no response, I'm out.

Comment: This query will never return any result : `number` cannot be `NULL` and `NOT NULL` at the same time ! 

You probably want to use an `OR` operator : `WHERE (id = 7 AND year = 45 AND number IS NULL) 
    OR 
        (id = 7 AND year = 47 AND number IS NOT NULL) `

Comment: OR gives me all values where number in year = 45 IS NULL which is good, but also gives all values where number in year = 47 IS NOT NULL. I only want to display the number in year = 47 if number in year = 45 is NULL

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

If I follow only your description I would try the following:

```
SELECT id, number_id, number, year
FROM tb_figures 
WHERE (year = 45 AND number IS NULL) -- if number IS NULL when year = 45
    OR (year = 47 AND number IS NOT NULL) -- if number IS NOT NULL when year = 47
ORDER BY number_id
```